# Can't access Hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this code:

```
price = variant[merchant["variant_code"]]
```

which translates to this: `variant["PRDCT-A"]`
but my problem is that it returns `nil` because my `variant` hash looks like this: `{:"PRDCT-A"=>{:price=>1495.0}}` it has `:` but I am passing just `"PRDCT-A"` which should be `:"PRDCT-A"`.

I have tried concat but it does not work, how can I include the colon so I can access the hash values?

Comment: Try `variant[merchant["variant_code"].to_sym]` which uses [String#to_sym](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym) to convert the string `merchant["variant_code"]` to a symbol.

Comment: Thank you for this! @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i am not wrong your hash structure might be like

```
merchant = {variant_code: 'PRDCT-A'}
variant = {:"PRDCT-A"=>{:price=>1495.0}}
```

and you want to access variants value with help of merchant hash

you should try this,

```
variant.dig(merchant[:variant_code].to_sym)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `with_indifferent_access` with `variant` hash like follow -

```
variant = variant.with_indifferent_access
```

And access again using same statement. i.e.

```
price = variant[merchant["variant_code"]]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Or simply `variant[merchant["variant_code"].to_sym]`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply convert to json and use it.

```
variant = variant.as_json

variant['PRDCT-A']
```